# How to call controller method when any key is press in textbox?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am very much new in angularjs.

I want to call my controller method using ajax call when any text is entered in textbox in angularjs.

I want to call my controller method on any key presses on textbox or removed.

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="newfriend.SearchText" required />
```

On any key press in this textbox i want to fire call this:

```
 $http.get('../Home/GetFriendsList').success(function (data) {
        $scope.friends = data;

    })
   .error(function () {
       $scope.error = "An Error has occured while loading posts!";
   });
```

Can anybody help me with this???

Comment: Provide Code please..

Comment: ng-keypress directive is there for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending my comment:

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="newfriend.SearchText" ng-change="myMethod()" required />

$scope.myMethod = function () {

 $http.get('../Home/GetFriendsList').success(function (data) {
        $scope.friends = data;
    })
   .error(function () {
       $scope.error = "An Error has occurred while loading posts!";
   });
}
```

Another way to call myMEthod function with updated value in textbox.

```
 <input type="text" data-ng-model="newfriend.SearchText" required />

$scope.$watch('$scope.newfriend.SearchText', function (newVal,oldVal) {
                 if (newVal){
                  $scope.myMethod();
                  }
              })
```

You are already  using ng-model. You can get that value in controller.
Just use ,

```
var  text = $scope.newfriend.SearchText
```

or, call myMethod function as

```
 <input type="text" data-ng-model="newfriend.SearchText" ng-keypress="myMethod(newfriend.SearchText)"
```

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67291/discussion-between-ved-and-maria-pithia

Answer (score 0):

either use `ng-change=function()` or `$watch()`